# How is $S^2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ locally?

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

Consider the [maps (page 169, M. Nakahara)](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=cH-XQB0Ex5wC&pg=PA154&lpg=PA154&dq=M%20Nakahara%20topology%20google%20book%20polar%20coordinates%20with%20different%20polar%20axes&source=bl&ots=2B-vz7zNBo&sig=kNj4-EXGKSmDV9VQEyS2IFAd-jM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGr7Tti-XTAhUBKo8KHVZkBaQQ6AEIITAA#v=onepage&q=M%20Nakahara%20topology%20google%20book%20polar%20coordinates%20with%20different%20polar%20axes&f=false) $$x=a\sin\theta\cos\phi, \hspace{1cm} y=a\sin\theta\sin\phi, \hspace{1cm} z=a\cos\theta\tag{1}$$ from the surface of a sphere $S^2$ of radius $a$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

1. From the maps (1), how can one understand that surface of a sphere $S^2$ is [homeomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism) to $\mathbb{R}^2$ locally? I want to unerstand, how does the maps (1) help us understand that surface of a sphere (or any *manifold*) *locally* Euclidean?
2. Why is (1) a map from $S^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ but not $S^2\to \mathbb{R}^3$? Is it because of the constraint $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: *Locally Euclidean* is a somewhat unfortunate term, as it implies the 'flatness' of Euclidean space, which the sphere of course lacks. What it really means to be a (2D) manifold is *locally topologically the same as the plane*. This just means that we can continuously map back and forth between given patches of our manifold and the plane (or equivalently an open disc in the plane). If you take the sphere and remove, say, some region of the north pole, you're left with something you can continuously flatten out into a disc. Likewise for a region of the south pole. Hence, a manifold.

Comment: Those maps don't go from $S^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$. They go from $(0,\pi)\times(0,2\pi)\subset \mathbb R^2$ to $S^2 \setminus L$, where $L$ includes both poles and a meridian joining them. You can handwave your way around the details but the fundamental direction is $\mathbb R^2\to S^2$, not the other way around.

Comment: @gj255 "This just means that we can continuously map back and forth between given patches of our manifold and the plane (or equivalently an open disc in the plane)". Why is the stereographic projection said to be a map between a "patch" on $S^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @SRS Because the stereographic projection doesn't map the north pole anywhere. That is, it acts on '$S^2$ minus the north pole', not the entire 2-sphere – it acts on a *patch* of $S^2$.

Comment: Ok. So the patch could be quite large. As big as the whole surface excluding the north pole. Am I right?

Comment: @SRS Precisely. For other manifolds, it could even be the whole space :O

Comment: @gj255 Not for any closed manifolds, however.

Comment: @gj255 You may put your comments as the answer if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly (re post v1), the sphere is NOT homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Suppose a homeomorphism existed. Then we could find a continuous $f:S^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$. $S^2$ is compact, and the [continuous image of a compact set is compact](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Image_of_Compact_Space_is_Compact), so $\mathbb{R}^2$ would be compact. Contradiction. (If you include the single point at infinity, you get a more interesting situation, [the Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere), which is $\mathbb{C}\bigcup \{\infty\}$ with a suitable topology, and is in fact homeomorphic to $S^2$)

To answer question 1, the [statement in question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold) would be to prove that "every point in $S^2$ has a neighbourhood which is homeomorphic to the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^2$". To do this, consider the point $a=(x,y,z)$ on the sphere. Consider the [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection#Definition) which sends $a$ to $(0,0)$ and sends $-a$ to infinity (ie, leaves it out of the domain). This is a continuous map with continuous inverse, and so it is a homeomorphism between a neighborhood of $a$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$.

To answer question 2, (1) is certainly not a map to $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is a map to $\mathbb{R}^3$, plain and simple.

Comment: So the maps I've given does not help me understand how $S^2$ is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. In what sense your map is locally Euclidean?

Comment: In M. Nakahara's book, page 169, he gives the map that I wrote. Please see the link in my question. @NeuroFuzzy

Comment: Look at the covering of $S^2$ by the stereographic projection to see a simple function from open sets of the sphere to open sets of the plane.

Comment: Your maps show how $S^2$ is embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @SRS The stereographic projection is a homeomorphism between $S^2$ with one point removed (so it's a neighborhood of $a$) and $\mathbb{R}^2$, so it works. The map you were given COULD be used. For example, if you remove the points at $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi$, and also remove the line holding $\varphi=\pi$ and letting theta run from $0$ to $\pi$, then this shows a homeomorphism between the open rectangle $\phi\in (-\pi,\pi)$, $\theta\in(0,\pi)$ and an open set in $S^2$ which covers most points. You would then have to consider multiple such maps to account for the boundary points.

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy But would you say that the maps I've given is from $S^2\to \mathbb{R}^3$ and not $S^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$? Is there a sense in which locally Euclidean can mean that local distances are Pythagorean or something similar?

Comment: @SRS It seems Nakahara is just using the map (5.1) to *define* spherical polar coordinates on the sphere. The map from the sphere to $\mathbb{R}^2$ which you're looking for takes a point $p$ on the sphere, computes its spherical polar coordinates, and puts them into a 2-vector $(\theta, \phi)$. Note that spherical polars are only defined when $\phi \neq 0, \theta \neq 0, \pi$, so we can only map some (well, most) of the sphere to the plane in this way.

Comment: @SRS Erm, well there's a map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ ($f(\phi,\theta)$) and an isometric map from the abstract object $S^2$ to the same subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Alternately, you could say $S^2$ is exactly equal to that subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$. And yes there is a sense! But that's sort of another question

Comment: Regarding $S^2\not\cong \Bbb R^2$, it is even easy to prove that no compact $n$-manifold smoothly embeds into $\Bbb R^n$ (the key is to realize that such an embedding must be surjective).